# Bootstrap Mobile Menu 100%

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a very long mobile menu with 4 menu items, each of those items has dropdown menus, the first dropdown is very long and when I'm scrolling through my nav with the first dropdown open, I can't get to the last dropdown in my menu, unless I close the first dropdown, but I would like to be able to get to the last dropdown even if the first dropdown is open.

Here is the HTML

```css
.navbar-collapse {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="~/Images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Option</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-communities" role="menu">
            <div class="row current-communities">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="current-communities-hr" />
            <div class="row upcoming-communities">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Option</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Option</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Option</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried the following:

```
.navbar-collapse {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

But I still can't get to the last dropdown when the first one is open.

Comment: Trying to recreate this in codepen. This looks like bootstrap 3, can you confirm?

Comment: Bootstrap v3.3.7

Comment: Can you see this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwVryP

Testing on Nexus 5x, I'm able to scroll down to your bottom option dropdown, even with the first one open

Comment: What about on an iPhone?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have one to test with. I'll post the codepen in the Answer and hopefully someone with an iPhone can confirm

Comment: kindly select the answer that solved your problem so the question can be marked as closed. Thanks.

Comment: @viCky _so the question can be marked as closed._ what did you mean?

Comment: as in, when you select the answer that solves your problem, in the list of questions, it will show a green background on the answer. So everyone can know that the question is solved and it does not need more input from anyone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap puts absolute positioning on their .dropdown-menu class. Simply position it relatively and you should be golden. See the modification in the snippet.

```css
.dropdown-menu{
  position:relative;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<style>
  .navbar-collapse {
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  }
</style>


<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="~/Images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Option 1</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-communities" role="menu">
            <div class="row current-communities">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="current-communities-hr" />
            <div class="row upcoming-communities">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Option 2</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Option 3</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Option 4</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

First of all `navbar` is fixed element so you can't scroll it even though it's overflowing in body element.

Now you are giving height `100vh` to `.navbar-collapse`

let say `vh = 300px`

Now `.navbar-collapse`'s height is `300px` but after expending it `navbar` height is `350px` (`.navbar-header` + `.navbar-collapse height`) and it will overflow body element which current height is `300px`.

Now you can only scroll `.navbar-collapse` not `navbar` that's why forth item is hiding.

You need to reduce height of `.navbar-collapse` by `50px` (height of .navbar-header).

```
.navbar-collapse {
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<style>
  .navbar-collapse {
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  }
</style>


<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="~/Images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Option 1</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-communities" role="menu">
            <div class="row current-communities">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="current-communities-hr" />
            <div class="row upcoming-communities">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Option 2</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Option 3</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Option 4</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried your answer and it didnt work....for my dropdown I have to do this `.navbar-collapse{height:calc(100vh - 200px)}` which lets me scroll to the last item when the first item dropdown is open, but there is a space at the bottom of my menu that exposes the page. My menu is #FFFFFF but not the whole thing with your code I tried.

Comment: In that case you should provide your proper code or a working snippet, my answer is working with current code provided by you.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is located in the selector `.navbar-collapse` which has set the `max-height` to `340px`. To work around it you need to first override that to your desire height and add `!Important` to override the existing style.

Also, you're using columns inside your menu, so you need to keep in mind that will break some of the bootstrap styling (like dropmenu style for instance). that's because how the selectors has been configured in a hierarchy structure. So, anything out of the bootstrap structure needs to be reconfigured in your favor (This is also applied in most CSS frameworks).

Here is the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/iSR5/pen/WOZNGj?editors=0100)

I have applied

```
.navbar-collapse {
  max-height: 90vh !Important;
  height: 90vh;
}
```

the `max-height` has been overridden with 90% of the vh on any device, that will make sure the menu will not exceed the device height. As you know most of smart devices has built-in tab navigation and the  address bar  located on top and bottom of the web browser. So, the 10% will take care of that, and make the menu appear correctly.

This code has been tasted on my iPhone 6 and it works just fine.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to set the **height**, but **max-height**.
In bootstran .navbar-collapse max-height: 340px;.
For mobile devices, the menu should occupy the entire screen.

```
<style>
  .navbar-collapse {
     max-height: calc(100vh - 50px)!important;
  }
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<style>
  .navbar-collapse {
     max-height: calc(100vh - 50px)!important;
  }
</style>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="~/Images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Option</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-communities" role="menu">
            <div class="row current-communities">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="current-communities-hr" />
            <div class="row upcoming-communities">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h4>Option</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Option</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Option</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Option</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Link/">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```